# problems with 8086 asm recursion

Tags: assembly, recursion, x86-16

What my ITEM3 procedure should do is to check if, on a "game of the goose" gameboard, the final destination of a placemarker is already occupied, and, if it is, go back until an empty cell is found. So I thought to use a recursive procedure. 
EDIT:

Here is the code:
the procedure is called after pushing the calculated position of the placemarker after the die has been thrown (or the award that the cell gives to the player has been calculated).

```
    ITEM3 PROC
    MOV BP, SP
    PUSHA
    MOV BX, [BP+2]    ;BX now contains the position to be checked.
    CMP BX, 0         ;if the placemarker is in the start cell,
    JE no_collision   ;there's no collision
    MOV DL, PLAYER    ;PLAYER is a variable containing 1, 2 or 3, pointing the player
;now some thoughts: if the player doesn't actually move (some "negative award")
;then there is no collision. So I check if the future position is already occupied, but
;I check if it is occupied by the same player, too. The following 6 labels are for this purpose
    CMP BL, P1_POS
    JE collisionp1
p2collision:
    CMP BL, P2_POS
    JE collisionp2
p3collision:
    CMP BL, P3_POS
    JE collisionp3
    JMP no_collision
collisionp1:
    CMP DL, 1
    JE p2collision
    JMP collision
collisionp2:
    CMP DL, 2
    JE p3collision
    JMP collision
collisionp3:
    CMP DL, 3
    JE no_collision
collision:             ;there's a collision. The placemarker goes back by 1 cell. Then the recursion start.
    DEC BL
    PUSH BX
    CALL ITEM3
    POP BX
    MOV [BP+2], BX
no_collision:
    POPA
    RET
ITEM3 ENDP
```

But, when the procedure is called, nothing happens to the placemarker. Where is the mistake? Thanks.

[Here](http://codepad.org/Jy2w86KY) you can find the whole code.

Comment: Use a debugger to single step your code and see where it goes wrong. Also, comment your code, especially if you want others to help. PS: Avoid recursion if possible.

Comment: @Jester
you're right, I was in a hurry. I added some comment on the code.
I tried to debug, but when the procedure was called the debugger didn't get into the procedure's code. I'll try again.

My goal, at the moment, is to make it work by tomorrow morning, if I can't, I'll switch to iteration.. but I want to change the least lines I can

Comment: *SOLVED*
BP register changed and I didn't see that.

Thank you all for the attention.

Comment: @EnricoBalsamo Both procedures ITEM3 and ITEM1C suffer the same problem. It's nice that you found a solution. Perhaps you could post a short answer showing how you solved it.

Comment: @user3144770 you're right, I've been rude. Here's the whole correct and working code http://codepad.org/VbblYEka

Comment: By the way I managed to make the debug work (I was just pushing the wrong Fn button) so I could understand that the BP register changed each time the procedure was called and that obviously it didn't reset to the previous value. So the MOV [BP+2], BX instruction was setting I don't know what cells of the stack to BX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old post but I think that a clear answer should be posted.

The problem was that the call to `ITEM3` procedure changed `BP registry` and so the following instructions involving `BP` didn't act correctly.

The solution is just to `PUSH BP` before calling the procedure and then popping right after.

```
    ITEM3 PROC
    MOV BP, SP
    PUSHA
    MOV BX, [BP+2]
    CMP BX, 0
    JE no_collision
    MOV DL, PLAYER
    CMP BL, P1_POS
    JE collisionp1
p2collision:
    CMP BL, P2_POS
    JE collisionp2
p3collision:
    CMP BL, P3_POS
    JE collisionp3
    JMP no_collision
collisionp1:
    CMP DL, 1
    JE p2collision
    JMP collision
collisionp2:
    CMP DL, 2
    JE p3collision
    JMP collision
collisionp3:
    CMP DL, 3
    JE no_collision
collision:
    DEC BL
    PUSH BP                 ; HERE
    PUSH BX
    CALL ITEM3
    POP BX
    POP BP                  ; AND HERE
    MOV [BP+2], BX
no_collision:
    POPA
    RET
ITEM3 ENDP
```